# Exclude nulls from result SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query which returns result, contains dates mixed with null values.
My goal is to remove nulls from all columns by merging values.

Note: it's guaranteed that amount of dates in both columns DateFrom and DateTo are equal.

Currently I am getting the following from my query

```
Client_Id   DateFrom         DateTo          
----------- ---------------- ----------------
          9             NULL             NULL
          9       2023-11-23             NULL
          9             NULL             NULL
          9             NULL       2023-12-22
          9             NULL             NULL
          9       2024-01-05             NULL
          9             NULL       2024-01-12
          9       2024-01-13       2024-02-03
```

What I would like to get is:

```
Client_Id   DateFrom         DateTo          
----------- ---------------- ----------------
          9       2023-11-23      2023-12-22
          9       2024-01-05      2024-01-12
          9       2024-01-13      2024-02-03
```

I have no idea how to achieve this.

The dataset, table and select which returns my result follow.

```
CREATE SCHEMA [TestDoc]
CREATE TABLE [TestDoc].[Contracts]
(
[Id] Int NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
[Type_Id] int NOT NULL,
[Client_Id] int NOT NULL,
[DocNo] NVarChar(50) NOT NULL,
[DateFrom] Date NOT NULL,
[DateTo] Date NULL,

PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED([Id])
)
GO

INSERT INTO TestDoc.Contracts
VALUES
(2, 9, '#dc4887311699','2023-11-08', null),
(2, 9, '#dc4887311699','2023-11-10', '2023-11-20'), --should not be selected
(2, 9, '#dc4887311699','2023-12-10', '2023-12-14'),
(2, 9, '#dc4887311699','2023-12-12', '2023-12-20'),
(2, 9, '#dc4887311699','2023-12-18', '2023-12-22'),
(2, 9, '#dc4887311699','2023-12-23', '2024-01-11'),
(2, 9, '#dc4887311699','2024-01-05', '2024-01-08'),
(2, 9, '#dc4887311699','2024-01-09', '2024-01-12'),
(2, 9, '#dc4887311699','2024-01-13', '2024-01-24')

declare 
  @Type_Id int = 2,
  @DateBegin date = '20231123',
  @DateEnd date = '20240203'

  select Client_Id, 

  DateFrom = case when lag(a.DateTo) over(partition by Client_Id order by DateTo) is null then @DateBegin 
    else
      case when datediff(day, lag(a.DateTo, 1, @DateBegin) over(partition by a.Client_Id order by a.DateTo), a.DateFrom) >= 1 then a.DateFrom end
    end,
    
  DateTo = case when lead(a.DateFrom) over(partition by Client_Id order by DateFrom) is null then @DateEnd
   else
      case when datediff(day, a.DateTo, lead(a.DateFrom, 1, @DateEnd) over(partition by a.Client_Id order by DateTo)) >= 1 then a.DateTo end
   end

  from 
  (
    select Client_Id,

    DateFrom = case when DateFrom < @DateBegin then @DateBegin else DateFrom end,
    DateTo = case when (DateTo > @DateEnd) or (DateTo is null) then @DateEnd else DateTo end

    from TestDoc.Contracts
    where (DateFrom < @DateEnd) and (isnull(DateTo, @DateEnd) > @DateBegin) and Type_Id = @Type_Id
  ) a
  order by a.Client_Id, a.DateFrom, a.DateTo
```

I'm using:

> Microsoft SQL Server 2022 16.0.4095.4

For the full logic let's consider this image. Blue rectangles means date ranges between ds (date start) and de (date end).

[image: graphical representation]

So I have to return disjoint and non-adjacent ranges (at least one day difference) between `@DateStart` and `@DateEnd`. In this case ranges to return should be:
(@DateStart,de4), (ds5-@DateEnd).
**Note, in this case ds1 < @DateStart, so @DateStart should be returned. The same for DateTo and @DateEnd respectively.**
Also note, that DateTo can be null. In that case it means infinity.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a minimal reproducible example: (1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. (2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. (3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above. (4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: Your data sample contradicts what was said earlier in the question.

Comment: Are you sure? I copied exactly what got on output window. However i use [onecompiler](https://onecompiler.com/sqlserver/)

Comment: How about this: *"it's guaranteed that amount of NOT NULL values in both columns DateFrom and DateTo is equal."* It seems that your real question is about contract dates, not NULLS.

Comment: Exactly. Looks like I explained it wrong.

Comment: You need to explain the full problem, its not obvious to me, how you get from your provided sample data to the end result. You've done half the calculation, but the logic isn't clear. If you provide the logic someone should be able to find the complete solution.

Comment: You say that row 2 should not be included, but you don't say why. I can't see where datefrom "2023-11-23 comes from" etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can be sure that there will always be the same number of values of `DateFrom` and `DateTo` you can allocate each a row number then self-join on the row number e.g.

```
declare 
  @Type_Id int = 2
  , @DateBegin date = '20231123'
  , @DateEnd date = '20240203';

with cte1 as (
  select Client_Id
    , case when lag(a.DateTo) over (partition by Client_Id order by DateTo) is null then @DateBegin 
      else case when datediff(day, lag(a.DateTo, 1, @DateBegin) over (partition by a.Client_Id order by a.DateTo), a.DateFrom) >= 1 then a.DateFrom end
      end DateFrom
    , case when lead(a.DateFrom) over (partition by Client_Id order by DateFrom) is null then @DateEnd
     else case when datediff(day, a.DateTo, lead(a.DateFrom, 1, @DateEnd) over (partition by a.Client_Id order by DateTo)) >= 1 then a.DateTo end
     end DateTo
  from (
    select Client_Id
      , case when DateFrom < @DateBegin then @DateBegin else DateFrom end DateFrom
      , case when (DateTo > @DateEnd) or (DateTo is null) then @DateEnd else DateTo end DateTo
    from TestDoc.Contracts
    where (DateFrom < @DateEnd) and (isnull(DateTo, @DateEnd) > @DateBegin) and [Type_Id] = @Type_Id
  ) a -- Should use a more meanfingful alias here e.g. c for Contracts
), cte2 as (
  select Client_Id, DateFrom, DateTo
    , case when DateFrom is not null then row_number() over (order by case when DateFrom is not null then 0 else 1 end, DateFrom) else null end DateFromRowNumber
    , case when DateTo is not null then row_number() over (order by case when DateTo is not null then 0 else 1 end, DateTo) else null end DateToRowNumber
  from cte1
  where DateFrom is not null or DateTo is not null
)
select c2.Client_Id, c2.DateFrom, c3.DateTo
from cte2 c2
join cte2 c3 on c3.DateToRowNumber = c2.DateFromRowNumber
where c2.DateFromRowNumber is not null
order by c2.Client_Id, c2.DateFrom, c3.DateTo;
```

Returns as required

| Client_Id | DateFrom | DateTo |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 9 | 2023-11-23 | 2023-12-22 |
| 9 | 2024-01-05 | 2024-01-12 |
| 9 | 2024-01-13 | 2024-02-03 |

However if we could know your complete logic, there is probably a simpler solution.

Comment: Great thanks to you. That's literally what i need. 
I'll try to explain my logic in main post so i think there a lot easier solution for this.